# /bin/env : bad interpreter

Tags: bash, environment-variables, shebang

I am on Linux Mint 19.03.

I have a setup shell script file, `setup.sh`. When I run `./setup.sh`

```
muyustan@mint:~/Downloads/quartusExtracted$ ./setup.sh 
bash: ./setup.sh: /bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The shebang in `setup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/env bash
```

My understanding of these things are very narrow, since I am pretty new at Linux world.

I knew that, using `/bin/env bash` instead of giving the exact `bash` path was something like "search in the environment variables and try to find `bash`". When I look to `/bin` directory for `env`, I see that there is not such file:

```
muyustan@mint:/usr/bin$ ll /bin | grep "env"
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       6 Mar 21 14:35 open -> openvt*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   18872 Jan 22  2018 openvt*
```

Also,

```
muyustan@mint:~/Downloads/quartusExtracted$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

So, I assume that changing the shebang in the `setup.sh` to `#! /bin/bash` will solve the problem(I haven't tried), however, this does not seem very intuitive, because if so then I ask myself that,

" Did the developers of this application(Quartus 13.1) make a mistake? ", which leads me to think that something is wrong with my system.

So, the question is, why this is the situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Chnage `#!/bin/env` bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105942/discussion-on-question-by-muyustan-bin-env-bad-interpreter).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your system, you're just using the wrong path to `env`. On Linux systems, at least, the `env` binary is normally in `/usr/bin` and not `/bin`:

```
$ type env
env is /usr/bin/env
```

So, your script is telling your system to use `/bin/env`, which doesn't exist, and that's why you're getting that error. Simply change to the right shebang and you should be fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: Using `env` instead of `/usr/bin/env` also caused this issue for me, manifesting in a bizarre `sh: 1: my-script-name: not found` error when trying to invoke my script via `npx`. Thanks!